# Read whole nio Channel into a String

Tags: java, nio

I need to read a `ReadableByteChannel` (e.g. a `FileChannel`) into a string. I cannot do this by wrapping the channel with `Channels.newReader()` or `Channels.newInputStream()`, because I don't want the channel to be closed when the wrapper is collected. I also don't want to store all bytes in an intermediate `ByteBuffer`.

I wanted to read the input in a loop and call `CharsetDecoder.decode(ByteBuffer, CharBuffer, boolean)`, but the problem is that it will not reallocate CharBuffer when it gets full. The solution for that looks too complex:

```
public static CharBuffer readAll(final ReadableByteChannel ch, final Charset cs)
        throws IOException {
    final ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(3);
    CharBuffer cb = null;

    final CharsetDecoder dec = cs.newDecoder();
    while (ch.read(bb) > 0) {
        bb.flip();
        cb = mydecode(dec, cb, bb);
        bb.clear();
    }
    bb.flip();
    dec.decode(bb, cb, true);
    cb.flip();
    return cb;
}

// modified CharsetDecoder.decode(ByteBuffer)
private static CharBuffer mydecode(final CharsetDecoder dec, CharBuffer out, final ByteBuffer in)
        throws CharacterCodingException {
    int n = (int) (in.remaining() * dec.averageCharsPerByte());
    if (out == null) {
        out = CharBuffer.allocate(n);
    }

    if ((n == 0) && (in.remaining() == 0)) {
        return out;
    }
    // dec.reset();
    for (;;) {
        final CoderResult cr = in.hasRemaining() ? dec.decode(in, out
        // , true
                , false) : CoderResult.UNDERFLOW;
        if (cr.isUnderflow()) {
            // cr = dec.flush(out);
        }

        if (cr.isUnderflow()) {
            break;
        }
        if (cr.isOverflow()) {
            n = 2 * n + 1; // Ensure progress; n might be 0!
            final CharBuffer o = CharBuffer.allocate(n);
            out.flip();
            o.put(out);
            out = o;
            continue;
        }
        cr.throwException();
    }
    // out.flip();
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Could not get what you are trying to do.  But have 2 ideias that could help. 1. Store parcial decoded content in a StringBuilder and wrap it to CharBuffer after the read.  2. Allocate a bigger CharBuffer based on file size and trim it after the read.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any statement or evidence that a wrapping Reader or InputStream will close itself (and the Channel it wraps) upon being garbage collected.

But if you really want another way, you can use a Scanner:

```
public static String readAll(final ReadableByteChannel ch,
                             final Charset cs)
throws IOException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(ch, cs.name());
    String text = s.useDelimiter("\\z").next();

    IOException e = s.ioException();
    if (e != null) {
        throw e;
    }

    return text;
}
```

Comment: That's not what I said, and it doesn't explain why the channel won't be closed when the stream is garbage-collected.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot do this by wrapping the channel with `Channels.newReader()` or `Channels.newInputStream()`

Yes you can.

> because I don't want the channel to be closed when the wrapper is collected

It won't be. The channel won't be closed until the last reference to the underlying `FileDescriptor` is garbage-collected, or you close it specifically yourself.

You also appear to be unaware of [`CharBuffer CharsetDecoder.decode(ByteBuffer in)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#decode-java.nio.ByteBuffer-).

Your question is entirely unmotivated.